# Word vba - Read all values from INI file and put in array

Tags: vba, ms-word, ini

Ok, so I've got a bunch of Word templates that on Document_New reads the registry for some values and inserts these into bookmarks in the document. The way I've done this until now is to first read from an INI-file which dictates what the bookmarks in the templates are called. This is done line by line, which again is put into an array. Then I go through that array and read the registry one by one.

Now, is it possible to read the entire INI section and put it into an array directly?
Like this?:

```
Dim strIniKey as String
strIniKey = INI key

If bookmark exists strIniKey Then
   pick up registry string from strIniKey
   Insert into bookmark
End if
```

And just loop this through each INI value?

This is how I do it now:

```
    Dim objShell
Dim strShell
Dim strDataArea
Dim Verdier() As String
Dim regPath
Dim regString
Dim Felter
Dim WScript

' Klargjør stringverdier fra INI-fil

regPath = ReadIni(File, "Registry", "Path")
regString = ReadIni(File, "Registry", "String")
regStrFornavn = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Fornavn")
regStrEtternavn = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Etternavn")
regStrInitialer = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Initialer")
regStrBrevnavn = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Brevnavn")
regStrStilling = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Stilling")
regStrStilling_EN = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Stilling_EN")
regStrAvdeling = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Avdeling")
regStrAvdeling_EN = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Avdeling_EN")
regStrEnhetoffnavn = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Enhetoffnavn")
regStrEnhetoffnavn_EN = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Enhetoffnavn_EN")
regStrVisitaddress1 = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Visitaddress1")
regStrVisitpostnrsted = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Visitpostnrsted")
regStrPostadresse1 = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Postadresse1")
regStrPostadresse2 = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Postadresse2")
regStrPostnrsted = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Postnrsted")
regStrLeveringsadresseNr = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "LeveringsadresseNr")
regStrLeveringsadresseSted = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "LeveringsadresseSted")
regStrTelesentralbord = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Telesentrbord")
regStrDirekteinnvalg = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Direkteinnvalg")
regStrMobil = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Mobil")
regStrTelefax = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Telefax")
regStrWebadresse = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Webadresse")
regStrSentrepostmottak = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Sentrepostmottak")
regStrEpost = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Epost")
regStrForetaksnr = ReadIni(File, strRegArea, "Foretaksnr")

'Klargjør array av alle verdier fra INI-fil
Felter = Array(regStrFornavn, regStrEtternavn, regStrBrevnavn, regStrInitialer, _
regStrStilling, regStrStilling_EN, regStrAvdeling, regStrAvdeling_EN, regStrEnhetoffnavn, _
regStrEnhetoffnavn_EN, regStrVisitaddress1, regStrVisitpostnrsted, regStrPostadresse1, _
regStrPostadresse2, regStrPostnrsted, regStrLeveringsadresseNr, regStrLeveringsadresseSted, _
regStrTelesentralbord, regStrDirekteinnvalg, regStrMobil, regStrTelefax, regStrWebadresse, _
regStrSentrepostmottak, regStrEpost, regStrForetaksnr)
```

This basically creates an array full of the values from the INI file.

The code continues to take each part of the array and loop it through the bookmarks, searching to a match and then inserts the corresponding value from the registry.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    For iTeller = 0 To UBound(Felter)
    Dim sBookMarkName, sVerdi
    Dim myRange As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    sBookMarkNametemp = "Bookmark" & Felter(iTeller)

    sVerdi = ""
    sVerdi = objShell.RegRead(regPath & "\" & Felter(iTeller))
    sBookMarkName = ""
    sBookMarkName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(sBookMarkNametemp).Name

    With ActiveDocument
        If .Bookmarks.Exists(sBookMarkNametemp) Then
        Set myRange = .Bookmarks(sBookMarkName).Range
        myRange.Text = sVerdi
        .Bookmarks.Add sBookMarkName, myRange
        End If
        End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    objShell = Nothing
WScript = Nothing
```

Each bookmark is called "bookmark" + value of each line from the INI.
Like "bookmarkFIRSTNAME" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a Dictionary (from the MS Scripting library).

```
Dim oDict as new scripting.dictionary
Dim arrVals, x

arrVals = Array("Path","String","Fornavn") 'etc etc
for x=lbound(arrVals) to ubound(arrVals)
   oDict.Add arrVals(x), ReadIni(File, strRegArea, arrVals(x))
next x
```

Now you can reference your values as (eg.) :
    oDict("Path")

Still, all you've done there is move them from an ini file to a Dictionary: in both cases you just reference the values by name. Still, it's less code... 
I'm not sure of the purpose of first transferring them to an array ?  Is your code part of a function which just returns the array ?

Tim

Comment: No, it's probably written poorly in the first place. Basically, what I'm doing is loading data from the registry into predefined bookmarks in the template. The ini file tells the code the name of each key in the registry. Then it loads the data collected from the registry into an array and feeds each one in the corresponding bookmark that matches the same name. If you have any suggestions, please feel free to bring them :)

Comment: If you don't need to store the ini/registry lookup results but just need to insert then in the bookmarks, just take the looping approach, and readfrom ini > read from registry > insert to bookmark within each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I don't really need to store them no. I just need to look up the values from the INI files, go through the bookmarks and see if the bookmark is called "bookmark+INI value", then use the same value as the one from the INI key and pick up the value from the registry key and then insert it into the bookmark.

Comment: Is it possible the read the section of the ini file and create the array without having to specify the key? I want the code to go to a specified section in the ini-file, then read all of the strings and put them in an array. Then just go through that array and look for bookmarks and through the registry. But do that I need it to read the entire section and put it into an array. All without me having to specify each key in the ini section. I'm sure you understand what I mean, unless I'm very poor at explaining :p